# JavaScript true false not executing correctly in if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For some reason when I'm using the true/false values and checking if at least one of the values is true, the if/else statement is not working correctly. 
I have this:

```
 $scope.checkValues = function (qId) {
   var airport = $scope.airports[0].questID;
   var destAirport = $scope.destAirports[0].questID;
   var airportVal = isFalseOrUndefined($scope.answers[airport]);
   var destAirportVal = isFalseOrUndefined($scope.answers[destAirport])
   if (airportVal == false || destAirportVal == false) {
     $surveyNav.skipPage = true;
   }
 }

 function isFalseOrUndefined(val) {
   if(val == null || val === false) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

In this image below, as you can see the value for `airportVal` is true, the other value for `destAirportVal` in that same scenario is true, but I'm still able to get correctly in to the if condition and set the scope value.

[image]

Does anyone see any issue?

Comment: I don't see that the value of `airportVal` is true.  And trust me, it's either not, or `destAirportVal` is false.  JS is not fundamentally broken in your environment.

Comment: @Madbreaks you see that popup saying true, thats because I have the mouse over the airportVal var, here is another printscreen with destAirportVal http://gyazo.com/71dca4342a4166c24c07199d991ef73f thx for help

Comment: No but undefined could be assigned to a truthy value

Comment: Please. Just do some console.log calls on your vars. Because I don't see a mouse cursor anywhere, I don't know *what* you're hovering over.

Comment: @Madbreaks can you please have a quick join.me session with me, because I'm really running out of ideas, if you're very good with JS you'll help me in 2-3 mins. Thanks

Comment: The description on your question doesn't seem to match up with your code. You say that you are 'checking if at least one of the values is true' but your code is looking for if one of your values is false. So just because `airportVal` is true doesn't mean that `desAirportVal` is also true and therefore not going to enter the if statement. [I threw a plunk together that shows that your code should work if it is getting the correct values](http://plnkr.co/edit/6aR0RGMh622BCUTSXIxH?p=preview).

Comment: @MatthewGreen not really as you're saying, but thanks for the assistance. I would love someone to do a quick join.me or teamviewer session with me. But, I did your changes and see what I have. As you can see both values are false (http://i.gyazo.com/f81af4d7e5c5bf8c8a06c980b3f32796.png) and the code is still acting as at least one of the values are true (http://i.gyazo.com/1fa5a1f64e37ea1624add1f68b4233c9.png) What do you think about that? Thanks

Comment: One more example, before executing the if statement, I'm setting the values explicitly and I'm still able to get in to the if statement http://i.gyazo.com/23d7a5b5d87b8ebaf93a7b6472e13330.png

Answer (score 1):

You should be using === and !== operators when checking for equality in Javascript.
[Javascript Comparison and Logical operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

op1 === op2 - Will check if op1 is explicitly equal to op2

op1 !== op2 - Will check if op1 is not explicitly equal to op2

**Also:** you can condense you isFalseOrUndefined function

**Note 1:** you are not actually checking if val is undefined.
To check if something is undefined: typeof val === 'undefined'
This is different than checking if a variable is null

**Note 2:** Keep in mind that your variables are not entirely clear here.  airportVal will be equal to true when $scope.answers[airport] is false or null.  Is this your intention?

```
$scope.checkValues = function (qId) {
    var airport = $scope.airports[0].questID;
    var destAirport = $scope.destAirports[0].questID;
    var airportVal = isFalseOrUndefined($scope.answers[airport]);
    var destAirportVal = isFalseOrUndefined($scope.answers[destAirport])

    if (airportVal === false || destAirportVal === false) {
        $surveyNav.skipPage = true;
    }
}

function isFalseOrUndefined(val) {
    return (val === null || val === false);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the value of undefined

Answer (score -2):

Your function should probably do what it claims to do:

```
function isFalseOrUndefined(val) {
   return typeof val === 'undefined' || val === false || val === null || val === ''/* add this if you think it should be falsy*/;
}
```

But then, testing for `!val` should be sufficient:

```
$scope.checkValues = function (qId) {
    var airport = $scope.airports[0].questID;
    var destAirport = $scope.destAirports[0].questID;
    if (!airport || !destAirport) {
          $surveyNav.skipPage = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you forget to use the IsFalseOrUndefined function in the example?

Comment: This isn't an answer.  Also: `'' == false;  // true`.  Not sure how "empty string" means "false or undefined"?

Comment: Did you actually *read* my code? Don't you see the extra `=` char? It makes a lot of difference.